# Package mono app on ubuntu snappy

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I am developing a simple hello world console app in MonoDevelop under Ubuntu and it works fine. Now I would like to package it and to deploy as a snap to some
hardware running ubuntu-core. Can somebody please advise how to push this app on Ubuntu snappy along with its dependency if any....